# flutter - firebase messaging not showing in mobile phone

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to setup push notification to my mobile apps using flutter [firebase messaging](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging).

I have doing below things :

1. Setup firebase
2. Download google-service.json to android/app folder
3. Initialize firebase messaging at Home Screen

However, when I try send message from firebase console, my mobile phone **not showing the notification**.

By debugging I can see my mobile phone receive the push notif :

```
I/flutter (17004): on message {notification: {body: message 18, title: test 18}, data: {}}
I/flutter (17004): on message {notification: {body: message 19, title: test 19}, data: {}}
I/flutter (17004): on message {notification: {body: message 20, title: test 20}, data: {}}
```

But it show nothing on my mobile phone.

My flutter code at home screen :

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {     


FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();
    
      @override
        void initState() {
          // TODO: implement initState
          super.initState();
          
          _firebaseMessaging.configure(
            onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
              print('on message $message');
              //_showItemDialog(message);
            },
            onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
              print('on resume $message');
              //_showItemDialog(message);
            },
            onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
              print('on launch $message');
              //_showItemDialog(message);
            },
          );
          _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
              const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
              _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
                print('>>>token='+token);
          });
        }

 ...

}
```

I have tried to send messaging using FCM API via postman, but same result (get message in debug console, but not in mobile phone)

Any idea how to solve ?

Comment: do you have the app open when you are testing? If so that could be why. The notifications only show if the app isn't open IIRC.

Comment: Hi @MatthewClark you're right. now i can receive the message

Answer (score 2):

To add on what has been mentioned in the comments, Firebase Cloud Messaging Android SDK won't display the message on the notification tray [if the app is running on the foreground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages). Though the FCM SDK will still be able to receive the payload through the onMessage event, as displayed in the logs.

If you'd still like to display a notification while the app is visible, you can handle the onMessage event and display the payload using [`flutter_local_notificaions`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin. You can check this [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#android-configuration) on how to handle this use case for newer versions of `firebase_messaging`.